# How to upgrade Saxon debugging support from 9.2 to 9.5

Tags: java, saxon

I have an old application I am upgrading from Saxon-HE 9.2 to 9.5 (and hopefully to 9.8). The application implements the Saxon `Debugger` interface. After upgrading to 9.5, the `Debugger` no long fires any events. I thought this might be due to the byte code optimization, and set `GENERATE_BYTE_CODE` to false. However, I still receive no debugging events. I believe I found the issue, but don't know of the fix. In 9.2, `InstructionInfo` had a number of subclasses, including `StyleElement`. My code expects some `InstructionInfo`s to be `StyleElement`s, which they are not.

```java
public class Saxon2TraceListener implements TraceListener {
    // implement interface
    public void enter(InstructionInfo instruction, XPathContext context)
      {
        
        if (!(instruction instanceof StyleElement))
          return;
        // do logic with StyleElement
      }
}
```

How can I get a StyleElement from InstructionInfo?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid when you're working with low-level interfaces like this, there's no substitute for reading and understanding the source code. 9.2 and 9.5 are both unsupported releases, and in any case this is the kind of support that we only really offer to paying customers - we have to draw the line somewhere.

I think the actual `Debugger` interface has been obsolete for some time. Its original idea was to allow you to annotate a stack frame with the names of the variables occupying each slot, but that's now a standard product feature and doesn't require a custom debugger.

You seem to be talking instead about the `TraceListener` interface, which has certainly undergone changes over successive releases, inevitably since it gives you access to the internal representation of a compiled stylesheet which is something we are always tweaking.

I'm not sure what the situation was in 9.5 or 9.8, but in 10.x the argument to `TraceListener.enter()` and `TraceListener.leave()` has changed from an `InstructionInfo` to a `Traceable`, and every expression and instruction is a `Traceable`.

A `StyleElement` is a node in the tree representation of the source stylesheet, and the source stylesheet no longer exists at runtime, whether you're tracing/debugging or not.

Comment: I verified that API changes at 10.x from `InstructionInfo` to `Traceable`. 9.3 through 9.9 use `InstructionInfo`.